# Scrapy return a updated dict item back

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, scrapy

Im trying to scrape all details from a subsite. For each item is a new subsite that I want to retrieve additional information from. Im storing all information into a dict per item and per detail.

The **Problem is that I get duplicate items when yielding item dict items**, and I expect it has something to do with me parising the whole item in my function instead of only the updated dict items. However, **I have been successful in parsing only a updated dict item back to the the item.** Instead I get a new item of every updated dict item. I expect the problem either has to do with my *for loop*, or with my '*def parse_item_sub*' function.

To give a quick intro to what Im doing in the code;

1. Retrive id's from a database
2. Scrape the site into attributes for the
   item. Because the site contains several identical items, but varying
   information. I have created additional sub_items, that are scraped
   into the main item, as dictionaries.
3. Loop over each dict item that contains href, to get the information from that site and scrape it to the dict in the dictionary. '*item['subsite_dic'][position]*' Thereafter return the item **Is it possible to return the updated dict item of the item?**

**The Code**

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapeInfo.items import infoItem
import pyodbc


class scrapeInfo(Spider):
    name = "info"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.nevermind.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):

        #Get infoID and Type from database
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=dbname;UID=user;PWD=password')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT InfoID, category FROM dbo.StageItem")

        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            url = 'http://www.nevermind.com/info/'
            InfoID = row[0]
            category = row[1]
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url+InfoID, InfoID, category, self.parse)

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url, InfoID, category, callback):
        request = Request(url, callback)
        request.meta['InfoID'] = InfoID
        request.meta['category'] = category
        return request

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        infodata = hxs.xpath('div[2]/div[2]')  # input item path

        itemPool = []

        InfoID = response.meta['InfoID']
        category = response.meta['category']

        for info in infodata:
            item = infoItem()
            item1, item2, item3 = [InfoItemSubSite() for i in range(3)]

            # Stem Details
            item['id'] = InfoID
            item['field'] = info.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item['field2'] = info.xpath('tr[2]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item['field3'] = info.xpath('tr[3]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()

            item1['field4'] = info.xpath('tr[4]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item1['field5'] = info.xpath('tr[5]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item1['field6'] = info.xpath('tr[6]/td[2]/p/b/@href').extract()

            item2['field5'] = info.xpath('tr[5]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item2['field6'] = info.xpath('tr[6]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item2['field7'] = info.xpath('tr[7]/td[2]/p/b/@href').extract()     

            item3['field5'] = info.xpath('tr[5]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item3['field6'] = info.xpath('tr[6]/td[2]/p/b/text()').extract()
            item3['field7'] = info.xpath('tr[7]/td[2]/p/b/@href').extract() 

            item['subsite_dic'] = [dict(item1), dict(item2), dict(item3)]

            sub_href = [d['field6'] for d in item['subsite_dic']]

            # Below is the code that should send each dictionary item to get further information
            # I think it might be here that I have a problem
            position = 0
            for i in sub_href:
                if i:
                    url = 'http://www.nevermind.com/info/'+''.join(i[0])

                    yield Request(url, self.parse_item_sub, meta={'item':item,'position':position})
                    print i[0], position, url
                    position = position +1     
                else:
                    position = position +1

            itemPool.append(item)
            yield item

        pass

        # Function to extract additional info from the subsite, and return it to the original item.
        # This works and all the right information is extracted
        def parse_item_sub(self, response, category):
            hxs = Selector(response)
            position = response.meta['position']
            item = response.meta['item']

            subsite = item['subsite_dic'][position]

            item['subsite_field11'] = i.xpath('/td[2]/span/@title').extract()            
            item['subsite_field12'] = i.xpath('/tr[4]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['subsite_field13'] = i.xpath('/div[5]/a[1]/@href').extract()

            response.meta['item'] = item

            yield item

            pass
```

Comment: what do you mean by "return it to the original item"? when you yield items from a callback method, those items are already outputted by scrapy, every request is asynchronous, so the previous callback is not waiting for the next one to update "its" item

Comment: Sorry, I might be using the incorrect terminology. The problem is that my scraper creates several dictionaries, where I want some additional details scraped into these dict items that resides within an item.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question (or your code), could you specifically say which variable or which item is doing something incorrectly? maybe it also depends on the site, so no way we can't help without site information

Comment: As I see it the problem is either within my last for loop in `def parse(self, response):` or within the last function `def parse_item_sub(self, response, category):` I think the problem maybe caused by me yielding items from `def parse_item_sub(self, response, category):` and not the specific dict item. ex `item['subsite_dic'][position]`. Im very sure that it has nothing to do with the site, as I get all the correct information, though I get duplicates if a dict has multiple items, where I just wanted to add info per dict item